# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS issue with angular ssr

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, http-status-code-301

I am implementing my 301 redirect in my `server.ts` file. I redirect to 301 in my `server.get()` function:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    let incomingUrl = req.headers.referer;
    if (incomingUrl && (/.*\/resources(\/.*\/).*/.test(incomingUrl))) {
      let redirectedUrl = incomingUrl.replace(/.*\/resources(\/.*\/).*/, (a, b) => {
        return a.replace(b, b.toLowerCase().split('%20').join('-'));
      });
      res.redirect(301, redirectedUrl);
    } else {
      res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
        { provide: REQUEST, useValue: req },
        { provide: RESPONSE, useValue: res }
      ] });
    }
  });
```

I check if the incoming url contains 'resources' and if it does, I remove any instances of '%20' and replace it with hyphen. When I hit an original url (<base_url>/resources/Example%20Url), I see that the url does get multiple 301 redirects but at the end, I get a failed request with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and I do not get redircted to the new url as shown in the screenshot below. How can I resolve this issue and get my old url redirected to the new one? [image: Network performance for redirecting url]

Comment: Hi dude, did you found a solution for it?